# Why is my button OnClickListener in a RecyclerView not working?

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, android-imagebutton

I have a `RecyclerView` in which each `CardView` has few `buttons`.
Following is the code for `onClick` of the items in the `RecyclerView`.

```
lvOffers.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            String hisId = listOfOffers.get(position).getUserIdHis();
            selectedPosition = position;
            status = listOfOffers.get(position).getStatus();
            dateUpdated = listOfOffers.get(position).getLastUpdateDate();
            currentOfferId = listOfOffers.get(position).getOfferId();
            new GetUserPosts().execute(hisId);
        }
    }));
```

But when I add the code for the `onClick` of the button in the `Adapter`, it doesn't get called rather the `ItemTouchListener` gets called.

```
holder.ivPrimaryImageOfferFew1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both to work. Remove OnItemCLickListener and write onClickListener to Root view of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

remove that, it causes problems for click.

or also

```
rvExpertbooksList.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(ExpertBooksDetailsActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                })
        );
```

Remove `addOnItemTouchListener` of `RecyclerView`; it works fine